# Required input field missing in SOAP request to activate global custom action

Tags: javascript, xml, soap, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to activate a global custom action in dynamics 2015 which will in turn activate a plugin registered on it.  I am able to activate it when I mark the parameters to optional, and in turn activate the plugin I am writing. However, when the custom actions input parameter is set to required, it throws an error saying it was not supplied even though I am passing a key-value pair with a key of the required field name and a value of the entity logical name.

Custom action is set up using one input parameter (entityName) that is required.  Eventhough the key-value pair exists for this when it is sent, it does not recognize it and spits back that it was not supplied.

The XML being sent:

```
        var requestXML = "";
        requestXML += "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
        requestXML += "  <s:Body>";
        requestXML += "<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
        requestXML += "<request xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\">";
        requestXML += "        <a:Parameters xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
        requestXML += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfStringanyType>";
        requestXML += "            <b:key>entityName</b:key>";
        requestXML += "            <b:value i:type=\"d:string\" xmlns:d=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" + Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
        requestXML += "            </b:value>";
        requestXML += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfStringanyType>";
        requestXML += "        </a:Parameters>";
        requestXML += "        <a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
        requestXML += "        <a:RequestName>new_StartCloning</a:RequestName>";
        requestXML += "      </request>";
        requestXML += "    </Execute>";
        requestXML += "  </s:Body>";
        requestXML += "</s:Envelope>";

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.open("POST", util.getBaseUrl()  + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web", false)

        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");

        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");

        var response = req.send(requestXML);
```

Error message being returned:

> s:ClientRequired field 'entityName' is missing-2147220989Required
>   field 'entityName' is
>   missing2015-08-05T20:55:26.0627226Z-2147220970System.ArgumentException:
>   Required field 'entityName' is missing2015-08-05T20:55:26.0627226Z

Thanks for reading this far haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a:KeyValuePairOfStringanyType>`

should be

`<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>`